# How type assertions "as" work in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

Explain how `as` works please:

I have a simple interface.

```
interface myModel {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}
```

and there is a function that returns an object { } as myModel;

```
function getMyModel(): myModel{
    return {
        name: 'kek',
        id: 8,
        data: 'pew',
        names: '321'
    } as myModel
}
```

Why, if I add properties that are not in `myModel` , the compiler does not throw an error and logs an object with properties that are not in the `myModel` interface?

```
console.log(getMyModel());
//[LOG]: {
//  "name": "kek",
//  "id": 8,
//  "data": "pew",
//  "names": "321"
//}
```

**How does `as` work?**

And why if I write like this:

```
let test: myModel = {
         name: 'kek',
         id: 8
         data: 'pew',
         names: '321'
}
```

then on the line with `data: 'pew',` the compiler will highlight it as an error?

Comment: The second part of the question, the *Object literal may only specify known properties* has a lot of existing good explanations.

Answer (score 4):

`as` completely overrides type checking.

When you use it, you are **telling** the compiler that the object is of type `myModel` and it will treat it as such.

It is a way to tell the compiler that you, the programmer, know what type the object it better than the compiler does.

---

In your particular example the `as` statement is very clearly a lie.

It makes more sense when you have something like:

```
 const myHttpResponse = await fetch(url_to_user_json);
 const myUserObject = (await myHttpResponse.json()) as User;
```

...since TypeScript only knows that the `json()` method returns something that can be parsed from JSON (so a string, or a number, or any kind of basic object, etc, etc).

---

I generally prefer to avoid `as` entirely in favour of performing a runtime check with a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) so if something goes wrong (e.g. the API design changing and returning JSON in a different shape) then I can catch it early and with a clearer error message).